# Importing directly from a namespace package in setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, namespace-package

How to use a module as both a [namespace package](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#namespace-packages) and as a container for classes in a specific subproject? That is, how can I import something directly from a namespace package instead of its subpackages?

An example can make the question clearer.

## Three subpackages of `calc`

Suppose I want to create a namespace package called `calc`, and there are three projects on it ([sscce](http://sscce.org): [calcs.tar.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw9sT8pzNEH7Z0NoNW03eWJHM2c/view?usp=sharing)). The first one, found at the `calc-add` directory, has the following structure:

```
calc-add/calc/
calc-add/calc/add.py
calc-add/calc/__init__.py
```

The content of `calc-add/calc/__init__.py` is just

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

as required by namespace packages, and `add.py` has only the following function:

```
def op(n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2
```

There is another project, at the `calc-sub` directory, has the following structure:

```
calc-sub/calc/
calc-sub/calc/sub.py
calc-sub/calc/__init__.py
```

The `__init__.py` file is identical to the previous one and `sub.py` has only a simple function:

```
def op(n1, n2):
    return n1 - n2
```

Finally, I have a `calc-main` directory with the following content:

```
calc-main/calc/
calc-main/calc/main.py
calc-main/calc/__init__.py
```

Again, the `__init__.py` has only the mentioned line, yet `main.py` has the following code:

```
import calc.add, calc.sub

def apply(n1, n2, op):
    if op == "add":
        return calc.add.op(n1, n2)
    else:
        return calc.sub.op(n1, n2)
```

## How do I call and how *would* I call the `apply()` function

If I invoke the Python interpreter with `$PYTHONPATH` set as below:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:../calc-add/:../calc-sub/ python
```

then I can call `apply()` this way:

```
>>> import calc.main
>>> calc.main.apply(2, 3, 'add')
5
```

However, I would like to call `apply()` directly from `calc`, as below:

```
>>> import calc
>>> calc.apply(2, 3, 'add')
5
```

It apparently works if I add the following line to `calc-main/calc/__init__.py`:

```
from main import apply
```

However, setuptools documenation is very clear:

> You must NOT include any other code and data in a namespace package's __init__.py. Even though it may appear to work during development, or when projects are installed as .egg files, it will not work when the projects are installed using "system" packaging tools -- in such cases the __init__.py files will not be installed, let alone executed.

So how can I get what I want without breaking the restriction on `__init__.py` files? Is that possible?

Comment: I think you cannot work around this very easily... my solution was move everything to first level namespace "core" package, in your case it would be `calc.core`.

Comment: Also you can use dot in namespaced package names, e.g. `calc.add` instead of `calc-add`. Most of namespaced Python packages do this.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa don't worry, in my examples the package are indeed dot-separated. The hyphenated directories are only the root directories of my hypothetical projects. Also, I'm using almost exactly the solution you proposed so far - just calling the module `main` instead of `core`. I'll keep looking - and waiting - for an answer, however.

Comment: That restriction comes from the fact that any namespace package can be the first one on sys.path. Then it calls pkg_resources.declare_namespace and/or pkgutil.extend_path which scan rest of sys.path to find more copies of namespace package and add those to package's __path__. If you provide any other code in __init__.py then you MUST duplicate the same code in EACH __init__.py, since any copy can "win" the race to be imported first depending on sys.path.

Comment: And for the record Python has builtin `apply` function https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply so maybe you shouldn't hijack this name.